# Ruby on Rails Rake migrate logs .0030s but takes 10 seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rake, cmd

This is a rather quick question, but I am unsure how to title it to find relevant results. I amusing RoR on a windows environment with all of the normal initial set ups. I have experienced a huge slow down between typing a command and it actually performing.

The latest example is doing a simple rake db:migrate, it is adding a very simple table to a brand new project and it states that it created the table in .0030s and migrated in .0040s. However between me pressing enter for the command and this actually displaying is around 10 seconds. This happens for everything from a generate to starting the server.

Is this common? Or is there something on my system that is causing it?

Sorry, I am using Rails 3.2.1 (took about 1.5 seconds to get that data even)

Comment: Just curious, which version of ruby?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using ruby 1.9.3p125

Answer (score 1):

The chrono starts once the Rails environment is loaded... and this is what takes much time.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is slower on windows than linux.  If you are running 1.9.2, try changing to 1.9.3, which has speed improvements for slow "require"s.  http://groups.google.com/group/railsinstaller/browse_thread/thread/58666fec49323310?pli=1